# 10K Tools Page Broken on SuperUser

Tags: bug, status-completed, interface, 10k

Currently when using any of the links on the 10K+ users page the links are generating wrong.

When clicking on Close/Delete the url is generated as <kbd>tag=Close</kbd> instead of <kbd>tab=Close</kbd>

**Just tested Rev: 2010.8.24.5 and this is still not working**

Comment: SU is a revision *ahead*, so good eyes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest revision. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62148/tab-links-on-recent-activity-page-dont-work/62169#62169)